# Does there exist a group $G$ such that ${\rm Aut}(G) = S_6$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

I thought this would be an interesting question, since every other symmetric group on $n$ elements is possible as an automorphism group, since ${\rm Aut}(S_n) \cong S_n$ for $n \neq 2, 6$. Obviously, $S_2 \cong C_2$ is a possibility... So is $S_6$ the automorphism group of any finite group? Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1237/is-rm-s-6-the-automorphism-group-of-a-group

Comment: Ah this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much!